# Whats the name of the codes (//-\\.*)

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

Please give the keyword for search on Google.. tutorials

First line in PHP file

```
    public function get_supported_url_patterns()
{
    return array('/https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?example\\.com\\/movies\\/[0-9]+\\/[^\\.]+\\.html.*/i');
}
```

2nd code

```
    protected function get_content_page_url_finder_pattern()
{
    return '|<a[^>]*href\\ *?=[\\ \'"]*?(https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?example\\.com\\/movies\\/[0-9]+\\/[^\\.]+\\.html)[\\ \'">]?|i';
}
```

1 example:

```
    protected function get_pagination_url_finder_selectors()
{
    return array('.pager a');
}
```

2 example:

```
if (preg_match('/240p[\'"]\\ *:\\ *[\'"]([^\'"]*cdn[^\'"]*\\.com[^\'"]*)[\'"]/i', $page_code, $temp)) {
            }
        }
        else {
        }

        str_replace('/', trim('\\/', '/', trim($temp[1])));

        if (preg_match('/480p[\'"]\\ *:\\ *[\'"]([^\'"]*cdn[^\'"]*\\.com[^\'"]*)[\'"]/i', $page_code, $temp)) {
            $result->add_video_file('480p', str_replace('\\/', '/', trim($temp[1])));

            if (preg_match('/720p[\'"]\\ *:\\ *[\'"]([^\'"]*cdn[^\'"]*\\.com[^\'"]*)[\'"]/i', $page_code, $temp)) {
            }
        }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Regular expressions or patterns

Comment: Thanks... Robby Cornelissen

Answer (score 0):

Those are preg patterns. Perl compatible regular expressions.